# Set date time format in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

One question for this problem, the changes I made seems no effect.

in main file i have as below code:

```
<tr id="trOrderDate" runat="server">
  <td class="padLOff" style="text-align: left"><b>Order Date:</b></td>
  <td><asp:Textbox ID="lblOrderDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ReadOnly="true" /></td>
</tr>
```

behind the **lblOrderdate** id, i have a code as below:

```
lblOrderDate.Text = order.Summary.OrderDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

The result will show as below:
[image]

I have tried to removed the format as below code to show the full data (date and time):

```
lblOrderDate.Text = order.Summary.OrderDate.ToString();
```

But the result still show as previous image.
I have checked the data in database have include the date time format.

Have any idea on the issue or any way for me to show the date and time.

Thanks

Comment: How do you wanna show your DateTime exactly?

Comment: try `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.ttt` - it means, day, month, year, hour, miniute, second, splitsecond

Comment: `lblOrderDate.Text = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss}", dt);`

Comment: Did any of the answers help you?

Comment: the answer works for me was  lblOrderDate.Text = order.Summary.OrderDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply:

```
lblOrderDate.Text = order.Summary.OrderDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

or

```
lblOrderDate.Text = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss}", order.Summary.OrderDate);
```

or like @fhogberg

```
lblOrderDate.Text = order.Summary.OrderDate.ToLongDateString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lblOrderDate.Text = order.Summary.OrderDate.ToLongDateString();
```

DateTime.ToLongDateString() outputs a formatted string with date and time.
It will be formatted in whatever culture is set as CultureInfo.CurrentCulture while manually specifying a format as comments and other answer suggested will produce the same result disregarding of CultureInfo.CurrentCulture

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11070054)

Comment: .ToLongDateString() outputs the full date and time as the question asks for. Should i have explained more why and written a more detailed answer? I'm new here and would like to know why this wasn't a answer to learn and not do the same mistake again.

Comment: Yes, though your code may be correct, it will be appreciated to add a little explanation, even if you think it's self-explaining.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101979/discussion-between-fhogberg-and-rene-vogt).